# Fiber to the Home (FTTH) to PC installation

Tags: networking, internet, pci-express, isp, fiber

My ISP installs FTTH (Fiber To The Home) like this:

> TP (Terminal Point) -> ONT (Optical Network Terminal) -> Router -> PC

Is it possible to use this method instead? How can this be achieved?

> TP (Terminal Point) -> PC (with a PCIe Fiber Optic Network Card)

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You would have to talk to your ISP in order to figure this out. There are multiple standards available so they'd need to tell you which kind of specs your card would have to meet anyway.

Comment: @DavidPostill because ISPs do not upgrade their router's dated OS which will most likely be running an ancient Linux kernel with ancient software with countless security vulnerabilities. It would be much better to have a PCIE card and let the PC's OS do the job. I do that with ADSL (ethernet card & DHCP), so I am wondering if the same can be done with fiber.

Comment: @Seth But where is the incompatibility exactly? In the PCIE card's firmware or in the PC's software?

Comment: @AndreYates Or buy your own router which is compatible with dd-wrt or tomato or whatever ...

Comment: It starts with the question whenever they use multi mode or single mode fibers? Do they use WDM? Those things are on a much lower level than OS. Regardless of this you will have to talk to them whenever they support that scenario.

Comment: Are you saying that the connection from the ONT to the router is fiber? Because if it's UTP Ethernet, why not just put your own router behind the ONT or plug the ONT Ethernet into your PC?

Comment: @Spiff The ONT -> router is RJ45. It depends, is the ONT also using  Linux? If it is, it will most likely be old and hackable. Adding a custom router is a suboptimal solution; the best solution is using only a PC.

Comment: Do you know exactly what kind of fiber system your ISP is using? Is it GPON or something else? I see on Amazon you can get a GPON SFP module for US$100 and an SFP PCIe card for US$200. Whether a solution like that would work with exactly what your ISP is running is a different story. Whether your ISP will allow customer-owned equipment connected in place of their ISP-owned ONT is another story as well.

Answer (score 1):

You must ask your ISP (which you haven't named) for the feasibility if that setup **and get the parameters**. Sorry for the poorness of this answer. Let me explain why this is hardly achievable

In my country, most ISPs will block you from using your own ONT for good and bad reasons (from the consumer-experience point of view). Pros is that they will optimize the machines' firmwares for best performance and **remote maintenability/telemetry**. Con is that they will strongly limit the configuration you can do on <strike>your</strike> their device. Forget about OpenWRT, VPNs and custom routing tables.

Following is a **speculation**. I suspect another reason behind this: consumer phone/data lines over FTTH, which means VoIP, must be bound to the wired line connection. Allowing to run custom hardware on the phone line (especially with unlimited-calls plans) exposes ISPs to the risk that good software developers create an application to route phone calls from/to their cell phones, which damages the ISP's interest in selling mobile call plans. Think about it for a second: you run the router on your own desktop PC, with full access to the NIC. Who prohibits you from forwarding phone IP packets to remote locations via the same optic wire.

Using a PCIe optical card is feasible as soon as you know all the network parameters required by your ISP and they do not bind your cable to the MAC address of the ONT they deliver to you.

Also mind that if you use a PCIe card you won't likely be able to use phone over VoIP.